# Researchers nowadays communicate via screens, not papers. LaTeX is not the right tool to write for screens. Why is it still the go-to for writing?

Tags: writing, formatting, website, latex

Web format is interactive, easily to read on the phone, and the editors are as WYSIWYG like Word, but as customizable as LaTeX. Learning HTML/JS is much more useful than learning LaTeX. (Searching [HTML/JS](https://www.google.com/search?q=HTML%2FJS) in Google yields 1080 M results, while [LaTeX](https://www.google.com/search?q=latex) yields 780 M results.) You can archive, version and index a webpage like any PDF file. If one wants to have everything in one file, then webpages can do that. In fact [that's what PDF does: compress multiple files into one file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10547890/3416774). If the medium is computer screens, then I only see it has advantages over using PDF.

I know that we still need to use paper as the medium here and there (we call papers as *papers*, not *files*), but isn't that only in that case that we should learn [typesetting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typesetting)? If the author doesn't care what medium the intended audience will read on, then why not using web format, as I think it is more popular these days? If the readers only need to read it in papers for some reasons (like it's better for their brains to read and write with pen and paper) and actually doesn't care about beautiful styling, then the print command is enough for that.

Or is it just that the new medium needs more time to widely adopted? In that case can we expect that more journals will accept web format submission in the future? Or if not, then what makes us expect that the intended audience will read the papers on paper?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151784/discussion-on-question-by-ooker-researchers-nowadays-communicate-via-screens-no); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: It's not clear to me why this question is so heavily downvoted. If you disagree with OP's sentiment, then write or upvote an answer explaining why. I think the question itself is reasonable and within the scope of this message board.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think your primary assumption, that LaTeX compiled to PDF is unsuitable for screens, is just wrong.

Instead of asking why authors should not use web format if they don't care what medium content is read in, ask yourself if authors really should not care what medium content is read in. In my opinion, both as an author and reader, they should!
Remember that papers do not just exist to contain results but also to present them. In this regard, for example, it makes quite a difference if the key comparison of two plots is presented side-by-side, top-bottom, single-page... or arbitrarily strewn throughout prose. There are many visual parts in a paper - even formula heavy ones - and their readability and impact depends on the layout.

In that regard, being inflexible and unresponsive is not a deficiency for papers, it is a feature. Raw web content is notorious for having [looks somewhere between beautiful and unreadable depending on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718201/unicode-box-drawing-does-not-render-correctly-in-browsers). Making proper responsive cross-platform pages is a time-consuming art in its own right. Heck, reading improperly responsive, improperly cross-platform content is time consuming!

Avoiding that effort by simply enforcing a well-defined layout for everyone is an efficient and effective solution.

---

At the end of the day, people writing documents from source *will* be using a typesetting markup language. Regardless whether they are using "web technology", many scientists will need something like LaTeX anyway. There's KaTeX, there's MathJax, there's [whatever MS Office uses](https://superuser.com/questions/340650/type-math-formulas-in-microsoft-word-the-latex-way) and they all look like LaTeX. Even if you use HTML/JS, or Markdown, or Jupyter, you will still use something very much like LaTeX.

For many scientists, learning LaTeX isn't some huge extra effort. It's something they have to do anyway.

Comment: "For most scientists, learning LaTeX [is] something they have to do anyway." Citation needed. There are other sciences besides physics and computer science. You said "At the end of the day, people will be using a typesetting markup language" but then you talk about math typesetting. Those are different things, and even fewer scientists typeset equations.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- True, I've made the statement on scope less general. FWIW, I would claim that many typesetting systems are conceptually similar (in the sense of "you learn programming, not language X") but indeed outside of equations this quickly becomes more abstract than concrete.

Comment: Ok, but by "people will be using a typesetting markup language" do you mean "... to typeset equations"? Most people I know write their papers in Google Docs or Word without touching a "typesetting markup language"

Comment: As a scientist with equations in almost every paper I've written, I have yet to use anything other than a WYSIWYG document creation program. Usually msword, and there usually with whatever equation tool is bundled with it.  I would put forward the hypothesis that THAT and NO learned markup language is the default and dominant condition.  I also expect any publisher to have a web format and PDF format display of my papers, without me doing my own markup. 99% of the time this expectation has been correct in the past 20 years. I mean, they need to use those fees for _something_.

Comment: I agree that being forced is also a feature. That's basically what WYSIWYG or type system does. Beside size, position or font, there are also browser engine and language version to consider. Different [browser engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_engine) can result in different layouts and renderings. And if HTML/JS has a new version, then you have to update the browser engine if you want new syntax be supported. Whereas if TeX has a new version, you don't have to update your PDF reader.

Comment: Nevertheless, I think theoretically we can have a standardized engine, and in your document you can specify what elements you want to be laid out and rendered exactly as you wish (I'll coin the term What-You-See-Is-What-I-See), and what elements the readers (and their browsers) can freely decide to display (What-You-See-Is-What-You-Decide). It's possible that there is one already. Do you think it also satisfies this need?

Comment: @Ooker There is a widespread What-you-see-is-what-I-see standard. It is called PDF.

Comment: @TimRias I know. It's just that HTML is also widespread and I think theoretically can be made WYSIWIS as well.

Comment: @Ooker Theoretically maybe, but after decades of people trying, I think it is safe to conclude that is a pipe dream.

Comment: @TimRias can you elaborate on why is that?

Answer (score 15):

Several major commercial publishers (e.g., Springer, Elsevier) do publish both PDF and HTML versions of articles, so the end format is either.

> I know that we still need to use paper as the medium here and there (we call papers as papers, not files), but isn't that only in that case that we should learn typesetting system?

The need to learn typesetting programs such as LaTeX is field specific.
Furthermore, the need to learn LaTeX can be circumvented by learning markdown-based languages like R Markdown or Quarto.
Both of these can be compiled to many outputs such as HTML, ePub, PDF, and MS Office formats.

> If the author doesn't care what medium the intended audience will read on, then why not using web format, as I think it is more popular these days?

I would challenge this assumption.
Popular among who?
Web developers? Data scientists? Academics? The general public?
Most non-academics I know use Word and even most academics in my field use Word to write documents.

> Or is it just that the new medium needs more time to widely adopted? In that case can we expect that more journals will accept web format submission in the future? Or if not, then what makes us expected that the intended audience will read the papers on papers?

I encourage you to push your envelope and expand your horizon.
Specifically, explore how other people publish who do not follow the traditional methods.
Tools like Quarto allow people to write in one language and compile to many other languages.
Examples include

- [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/) that is both an author hosted website and a Book from O'Reilly Press
- [Python for Data Analysis](https://wesmckinney.com/book/) that is both an author hosted website and a Book from O'Reilly Press
- [Modern Dive](https://moderndive.com/) that is both an author hosted website and book from CRC Press
- Many other book coauthored by Hadley Wickham that are listed on his [website](https://hadley.nz/)
- The [Quarto GitHub repo for journal articles](https://github.com/quarto-journals/)
- The [rticles package for R Markdown](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles)

For your last question:

> Why aren't more papers written in web format?

How do you know how papers are written?
You only see the output from the journal.
Most people I know and work with use MS Word.
This is neither a web format nor a typesetting program.
Personally, I try to use Quarto.
Most *mathy* people I know use LaTeX.

Comment: I understand why people prefers a low learning curve, WYSIWYG program like Word. But when the project is complex and they have to pick a programming language to learn, then assuming the effort to learn is the same, then why not choosing a more popular, more interactive, and intended for screens? I haven't looked closely at Quarto, but at the face of it I would put it in the same basket with webpage. Jupyter is the same: interactive and intended for screens, not papers. (I agree using "webpage" limits my options)

Comment: Quarto is a Markdown-based language that can go to HTML or PDF simply by changing one line of code for most files. Also, Quarto can use Jupyter Notebooks as input files.

Comment: Also, I would challenge this view "then why not choosing a more popular, more interactive, and intended for screens?". Popular among who? academics or the general population?

Comment: So is it valid to put Quarto in the same basket with webpage? As for the latter, I don't think that matters, because I think the answer is both: popular among academics and general population. And even there is a set of people that it's not popular, then the popular point is not as important as the points about interactive and intended for screens

Comment: Yes. Look at the home page: Quarto does both interactive websites as well as print formats https://quarto.org/ one quote notes _Publish collections of documents as a blog or full website. Create books and manuscripts in both print formats (PDF and MS Word) and online formats (HTML and ePub)._ Another quotes notes _Engage readers by adding interactive data exploration to your documents using Jupyter Widgets, htmlwidgets for R, Observable JS, and Shiny._

Comment: "and they have to pick a programming language to learn" Who does, for what?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- who has complex documents that using Word is inefficient? And they do this for the job of writing them?

Comment: @Ooker writing things like theses, dissertations, books, and the like can be hard with Word. Historically, it would crash with large files. Depending upon the equations and cross referencing, Word also does not work well, although Word now includes LaTeX equations. Lastly, the legal field often still uses Word Perfect (see this review of the software https://www.pcmag.com/reviews/corel-wordperfect-office).  The review also lists cause where the author uses Word Perfect rather than Word.

Comment: @Ooker I'm sorry, I don't understand either of your sentences.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I mean people who has complex documents that using Word is inefficient has to pick a programming language to learn

Comment: @Ooker Yet, most people do just fine with Word.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I know. They are not in my scope

Comment: @Ooker But they are, you said "researchers" ... not "researchers who use LaTeX."

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- yes, I should have been more specific on the scope

Answer (score 9):

There are a few reasons that a publisher might consider and that would make HTML a worse choice than print or pdf.

One is that it is difficult in html to specify pages and citations often rely on pages. Is a page a screen? Does a page take many screens?

Another is the publisher gives up a lot of control over presentation to the browser that presents, and interprets, the html. Browsers might insert ads, for example. The publisher wants full control, rather than deferring to decisions of another entity, such as the browser creator or a web service provider.

Printing pdf to paper is usually more predictable than printing html pages.

Many browsers will support useful presentation of pdf, of course, and still preserve publisher interests.

Comment: HTML representations are often quite messy with all sorts of ancillary files and folders (see what you get when you save a journal paper in HTML view from the journal website). A PDF is packaged up nicely to be one file in a consistent format.

Comment: @JonCuster One thing I like about Quarto documents are that the HTML files can be compiled to be self-contained.

Comment: @JonCuster you can simply compress it into one file. In fact [that's what PDF does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10547890/3416774)

Comment: PDF has now been around for 30+ years, an open format for 15. It likely will be around in another 30 or more given the widespread adoption across many areas. Almost anything can make PDFs (at worst through a ‘printer’ driver). It isn’t going away. It just works.

Comment: *it is difficult in html to specify pages and citations often rely on pages.* – In HTML you can anchor a heading, and hover the information for citation. *Is a page a screen? Does a page take many screens?* – Well, you can set it however you like. This very web page take multiple screens, for example. *Browsers might insert ads* – The same argument can be applied to PDF as well. PDF readers might insert ads (lots of them!).

Comment: *The publisher wants full control, rather than deferring to decisions of another entity, such as the browser creator or a web service provider.* – You can send them the source code, be it webpage or LaTeX, and they can control the content and style as their wish.

Comment: *Printing pdf to paper is usually more predictable than printing html pages.* – My counter-argument is the second paragraph in the question: except that the intended audience is expected to read on well-designed papers, then there is no strong motivation to use LaTeX. The authors can use whatever technology that is convenient for them, and I argue that webpage is usually more convenient. *Many browsers will support useful presentation of pdf, of course, and still preserve publisher interests.* – Good point. You can read a pdf in a web browser, but you can't read a webpage in a PDF reader.

Answer (score 7):

One of the main reasons that TeX (and its off shoots) are so popular in math heavy subjects like physics of mathematics, is that provides a robust, flexible way of reliably typesetting mathematical equations. So far this is the easiest (least inconvenient?) to use of various alternatives that have been introduced.

This is so much so that even in the web domain TeX is the go to tool for typesetting equations on the web. See an equation on Stack Exchange? It has been typeset using TeX. See a complicated equation on Wikipedia? It has been typeset in TeX. Same throughout the internet. And while integration of TeX equations in web formats using things like mathjax works, the typesetting can be a bit janky, especially when used inline. Consequently, when writing equation heavy texts, it makes sense to native write in a TeX derivative (only insane people still write in native TeX).

Answer (score 3):

If your contention is that HTML is easier to write by hand than LaTeX, then I suggest that that is just not true. HTML was perhaps meant to, but in practice is not reasonably created by hand. It is definitely much harder to read than LaTeX sources, principally because of the lack of enclosing braces, using the `<tag> ... </tag>` style that is much more distracting to the eye.

One could perhaps, though to a lesser degree, level the same criticism on LaTeX. In the end, both should today be written with WYSIWYG editor, at which point the debate becomes pointless: If you're writing either in a WYSIWYG editor, what it outputs at the end no longer matters.

What *is* relevant, however, is that formulas are written in the fundamentally same way: MathJAX uses a syntax pretty similar to what LaTeX uses.

Comment: It seems that I mistake the syntax (LaTeX) and the engine (TeX) (see [What is the difference between TeX and LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49/50146)). I have no problem with using the LaTeX syntax. MathJax seems to be the best of both worlds: it converts the LaTeX syntax to HTML/JS

Answer (score -8):

I think the answer is simply that LaTeX has a large network effect, and the benefit of interactiveness and responsiveness is small, making it still the dominant recommendation on writing complicate documents. Only when the interactiveness or responsiveness of the medium is necessary to convey the message that the authors have to use a non-LaTeX tool.

Food for thoughts:

- [The Network Effects Manual: 16 Different Network Effects (and counting)](https://www.nfx.com/post/network-effects-manual)
- [What advantage does *TeX provide over modern tools like HTML+CSS+js?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448032/50146)
- [Why books donʼt work](https://andymatuschak.org/books/)
- [How can we develop transformative tools for thought?](https://numinous.productions/ttft/)

Comment: There are latex tools which allow responsiveness, see e.g. https://hint.userweb.mwn.de/hint/format.html